# Replace text with image in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, railscasts

I followed the Railscasts for infinite scrolling on my Rails app.

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

Here is the coffeescript file and as you can see, when you get to the bottom of the page the text "Fetching more" displays. How can I replace this with a gif I have in my files??? `/assets/load.gif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.pagination').html('<%= image_tag("load.gif") %>');
```

You need to rename your coffeescript file to script.js.coffee.erb or you can use absolute path

Answer (score 1):

So, I was having this same exact problem following the same exact railscast.  I tried the solution that 'deep' suggested but it didn't work.  My application was printing the path of what was inside the `.html(xxx)` tag.  I did some more searching and found that instead of `image_tag`, i had to use `<img src="xxx">`.

Hope this helps anyone else that may be having this issue.